# Simulated Check, Error when checking user inputted amount. c++

Tags: c++, c-strings, string-conversion

I have a program written that prints out a simulated paycheck. Everything is okay according to my teacher's standards except my loop checking the amount the user entered.

I get the amount the user entered and put it into a string. I then convert that into an int to check if it is within the bounds of 0 - 10,000. It either skips that check completely or the program crashes. Any idea why? It is in the getInfo function. I have to bring the amount in as a string. I will also eventually have to to this with string class objects as well.

```
void getInfo(int nameS, int dateS, int amountS, char name[],char date[],  char check[])
{
cout<< "Please enter the name of the recipient: ";
cin.getline(name, nameS);

cout<< "Please enter the date EX. mm/dd/yy: ";
cin.getline(date, dateS);
 do
 {
    if(strlen(date)!= 8)
    {
        cout<< "That was not the correct date format. Please Enter again. Ex. mm/dd/yy";
        cin.getline(date, dateS);
    }

 } while(strlen(date)!= 8);
    // Small check for the right size. Does not check for character.

cout<< "Please enter the amount: above zero and under 10,000: ";
cin.getline(check, amountS);
double quickCheck=atof(check);

//PROBLEM
    do{
            if(quickCheck>10,000 || quickCheck<0)
            {
                cout<<"That amount is not within the bounds. Please enter again.";
                cin.getline(check,amountS);
            }
      } while(atoi(check)>10,000 || atoi(check)<0);

    return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see without actually running all your code is when you write `10,000` in the checks - I don't believe c++ accepts commas in numbers. Try `10000` instead.

Also, you need to reassign quickCheck to the newly inputted value inside the `while` loop at the end (otherwise the check is only ever using the first value).

Finally - is there any reason why you do a double check and an integer check (`atof` and `atoi`)?

**ADDITION**

Just as an extra note, when you come to checking the user input more rigorously take a look at `stringstream`. You'll want to load the inputted `string` into the `stringstream` then send it into an `int` (or `double` depending what data type is supposed to be given by the user) and then send it back to the `stringstream` and then into another `string` - if the final `string` is the same as the original then the input was the right type so you can do the range checks, if they were not the same then the user wrote something like "hello bob" when you where expecting something like "10.4" for example (one of the helpers in my class took great joy in introducing me to this by hitting the middle of the keyboard and then pressing enter and watching my program go wild...)

Comment: It was that damn comma! I figured it out just before I checked this. Its a double just because I was trying all these things to get it to work. Was originally atoi. Thank you for the response!